# How to optimize the best in python for this program with good performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a BIG JSON file (as sample shown below) for my application having various variables with values as strings and integers. I would like to read this file and store in the different class variables for further processing. These class variables shall change based on the functionality. I would to know any ideas for further optimizing the below code. In the below code, I am explicitly copying the data without any list comprehensions or any best technique. Any ideas to avoid copying data as  **config.ID =str(self.data["id"]),  config.ACTIVE=int(self.data["isActive"])** and do an efficient way (If I have 1000 variables, need to write 1000 lines.

```
read_con.py
-----------

import json

class config:

  ID=None
  ACTIVE=None
  AGE=None
  NAME=None
  GEN=None
  COM=None
  EMAIL=None

  def __init__(self):
     self.data = {}

  def read_config_data(self, cfile):
     try:
         with open(cfile, 'r') as cd:
             self.data = json.load(cd)

     except Exception:
         print("Error in Read  file")
         self.data = {}

     else:
        # HOW TO AVOID COPY OF DATA AS BELOW.
        config.ID =str(self.data["id"])
        config.ACTIVE=int(self.data["isActive"])
        config.AGE=int(self.data["age"])
        config.NAME=str(self.data["name"])
        config.GEN=str(self.data["gender"])
        config.COM=str(self.data["company"])
        config.EMAIL=str(self.data["email"])

  def use_variables_modify_based_on_request(self):
       config.AGE=45
       config.ACTIVE=8
       config.EMAIL="x@gmail.com"

  def printvalues(self):
       print config.ID, config.ACTIVE, config.AGE, config.NAME, config.EMAIL

if __name__ == "__main__":
  obj = config()
  obj.read_config_data("sample.json")
  obj.printvalues()
  # Modifying the values of class variables in different functions.
  obj.use_variables_modify_based_on_request()
  obj.printvalues()



sample.json  file
-----------------

{
      "id": "59761c233d8d0",
      "isActive": 1,
      "age": 24,
      "name": "Kirsten Sellers",
      "gender": "female",
      "company": "EMERGENT",
      "email": "kirstensellers@emergent.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
 ...
 else:
    # HOW TO AVOID COPY OF DATA AS BELOW.
    config.ID =str(self.data["id"])
    config.ACTIVE=int(self.data["isActive"])
    config.AGE=int(self.data["age"])
    config.NAME=str(self.data["name"])
    config.GEN=str(self.data["gender"])
    config.COM=str(self.data["company"])
    config.EMAIL=str(self.data["email"])
 ...
```

Do this:

```
...
else:
    for key, value in self.data.items():
        setattr(config, key.upper(), value)
...
```

(there is no need for the `str` and `int` calls since the values are already the appropriate type)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But, if i have a class variable names as (e.g. ID2 ) different as json attribute (id). key.upper() mayn't work.  Can you suggest any another way. which overcomes these issue.

Comment: Well, there is no way the program can guess which json attributes names you want to map to what attributes. You can use a dictionary, and fill it with the names that are different only {jsonname: attrname} , and for names not in the dictionary use the name itself.